# How do I use Recruit Cards in Grand Battle?

Tags: grand-battle

I'm playing [Grand Battle](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=air.com.grand.battle.game.war) on Android, and yesterday I got a high level Recruit Card in my bag. However, I don’t know how to actually use the card. Could anybody help me?

Answer (score -6):

Go Generals icon and go to Recruit Generals section, and you will see "One in a Million", then select "Priority Use High Level Recruit" card, and that means you are using this card in priority. Then use it. Accordingly this card in your bag will be gone.

Comment: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/behavior